# rails has_many :through or has_many_belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I was faced with the problem of composing associations.

It turns out that

I have a `user`, `user` can have many `photo booths`.

also `photo booths` can have many `users`.

This problem is solved, but I have `Group photo booths`.

`Group photo booths` can have many `users` and many `photo books`.
So

`GroupPhotoBooth` has many `User` and `PhotoBooth`

`PhotoBooth` has many  `User` and  one `GroupPhotoBooth`

`User` has many  `PhotoBooths` and `GroupPhotoBooths`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_photo_booths
  has_many :photo_booths
end

class GroupPhotoBooth < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photo_booth
  has_many :photo_booths
end

class PhotoBooth < AplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group_photo_booths
  has_many :users
end
```

But this order confuses me very much. What do i do?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking here - could you clarify a little please?

Comment: I need to organize associations in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make associations between classes and each class is related to User.

Then you should only make 1 class as User and User has many 'N' associations.

isn't this enough?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_photo_booths
  has_many :photo_booths
end
```

Comment: ya, but `photo_booth` and `group_photo_booth` can have many `users`